# How to inform FutureBuilder that database was updated?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a group profile page, where a user can change the description of a group. He clicks on the description, gets on a new screen and saves it to Firestore. He then get's back via `Navigator.pop(context)` to the group profile page which lists all elements via `FutureBuilder`.

First, I had the database request for my `FutureBuilder` inside the main build method (directly inside future builder 'future: request') which was working but I learnt it is wrong. But now I have to wait for a rebuild to see changes. How do I tell `FutureBuilder` that there is a data update?

I am loading Firestore data as follows within the group profile page:

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getFiretoreData();
  }

  Future<void> _getFiretoreData() async{
    setState(() {

    this._future = Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(globals.userId.toString())
        .get();});
  }
```

The `FutureBuilder` is inside the main build method and gets the 'already loaded' future like this:

```
FutureBuilder(future: _future, ...)
```

Now I would like to tell him: a change happened to _future, please rebuild ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I managed it like this (which took me only a few lines of code). Leave the code as it is and get a true callback from the navigator to know that there was a change on the second page:

```
// check if second page callback is true
    bool _changed = await Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      ProfileUpdate(userId: globals.userId.toString())),
                            );
// if it's true, reload future data
_changed ? _getFiretoreData() : Container();
```

On the second page give the save button a `Navigator.pop(context, true)`.

Answer (score 0):

i would advice you not to use future builder in this situation and use future.then() in an async function and after you get your data update the build without using future builder..!

```
Future getData() async {
       //here you can call the function and handle the output(return value) as result
       getFiretoreData().then((result) {
           // print(result);
           setState(() {
              //handle your result here.
              //update build here.
           });
      });
 }
```

Comment: Any idea how I can update the build when I saved data on another screen?

Comment: do you mean you are saving data on a screen In an async method? and then you want to be informed  on another page correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I am loading the async future via initState. But this future is already 'delivered', so FutureBuilder only updates _getFiretoreData() is run again. But I managed to get it working - have a look at my answer if you're interested ;-).

Comment: actually i knew this i just didnt think you to go to a new page except now XD

Comment: one question do you go to a complete new widget to get the data only ?

Comment: I go to a complete new widget with a TextFormField to change the data.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_future == null) {
        // show loading indicator while waiting for data 
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
        return YourWidget();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to set any state. You just need to return your collection of users in your GetFirestoreData method.

```
Future<TypeYouReturning> _getFirestoreData() async{
    return Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .document(globals.userId.toString())
    .get();
```

}

Inside your FutureBuilder widget you can set it up  something like Theo recommended, I would do something like this

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _getFirestoreData(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<TypeYouReturning> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      if (snapshot.data.length == 0)
        return Text("No available data just yet");

      return Container();//This should be the desire widget you want the user to see
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. The documentation says: "The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted." So the future is loaded via initstate. But then it is 'finished' - data change does not rebuild FutureBuilder. So how can I notify it?

Comment: I have learned it from here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfagvy5xCW0 check 1:03:00 in the video. They teach you the exact same thing I have just answered. If you still think my answered is wrong leave the downvote, if not please revert it. Hope it clarifies things for you.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer - I never do it because I appreciate help here. I figured out a way for my issue. Have a look at my reply if you're interested.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Stream builder instead of Future builder?

```
StreamBuilder(stream: _future, ...)
```

You can change the variable name to _stream for clarity.

Comment: I am using StreamBuilder within my chat. I thought when I am only receiving 'onetime' data (which is only updated when saved), FutureBuilder is more cost efficient.